# Elementary exercise on cosets

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to solve an exercise in an elementary book of groups and symmetries. The problem is:

H subgroup of with $ind(G,H) = m$. Prove that $\forall g \in G, g^{m!}\in H $

My solution is:

${\rm if} \ \exists 1\leq i \leq m, \text{such that}\  g^i \in H, \ {\text{ the proposition is trivially true}}$

else $\forall\  1\leq i \leq m\ g^i \not \in H,\  \text{and since} \ g^i \not \sim g^j\ {\rm for}\  i \neq j$ where the equivalence relation is the partition of G in cosets of H here, we have a contradiction here, there cannot be m disjoint cosets not including elements of H.

Is it right and is there a more simple way of proving it?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what tools you have available, but the presence of $m!$ should make you think of the symmetric group $S_m$.

To make this connection explicit you need to use action of $G$ on $G/H$ by left multiplication ($g.(xH)=(gx)H$). This is equivalent to having a homomorphism
$$\phi: G\longrightarrow Sym(G/H)\cong S_m$$
Now, $\phi(g^{m!})=\phi(g)^{m!}=(1)\in S_m$ (since $|\phi(g)|$ divides $|S_m|=m!$).

Translating back to the language of group actions, we now have that $$g^{m!}.(xH)=xH$$ for all cosets $xH\in G/H$. When $x=1$, this reads $H=g^{m!}.H=g^{m!}H$. That is, $g^{m!}\in H$.